# Vagrant mount error after installing Docker

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm getting a strange error in my vagrant VM. So I created a new ubuntu/trusty64 VM using VirtualBox (on OS X if anyone cares).

All fine there...

Then I installed Docker as per the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) which basically involves running

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

That works fine too.

Then I go to reboot the VM, I exit the ssh shell, and run `vagrant reload` and I get this error message.

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

stdin: is not a tty
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use Docker as a provisioner? http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html instead of installing it in the VM.

Comment: @iris-g: there are several reasons why one would do so. The most obvious is that docker still runs best on a native Linux platform. But when you want to share the development environment of your project with your colleagues working on other platforms like Windows and Mac it is easier. You just tell them to install Vagrant and VirtualBox instead of docker. With Vagrant you could provision a complete development environment with one `vagrant up` command whereas with a plain docker installation you need to assemble all containers by hand which is much more effort to do. Also with docker-compose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced similar issues. Looks like Docker (and potentially other tools) when installed will update the kernel version in your `Ubuntu/Trusty64` guest. Since the VBox GuestAdditions that came preinstalled in `Ubuntu/Trusty64` were specifically built against the original kernel version, the Guest Additions will stop working in the next `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload` as that's when the new kernel installed by Docker kicks in. At that point, Vagrant is no longer able to auto-mount `/vagrant` folder (or any synced folder for the matter) as the Guest Additions were built against a different kernel.

To get them working again you'd have to rebuild the GuestAdditions against the new kernel version that Docker installed.

Luckily, there's a plugin in Vagrant called `vagrant-vbguest` that takes care of automatically rebuilding the Guest Additions when the plugin detects they need to be rebuilt (i.e. like when the kernel in the guest changes, or you upgraded your VirtualBox version in the host)

So in my case, the easy way to fix it was to:

- On the host: `$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`
- On the guest: `$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
- On the host: `$ vagrant reload`

Thanks to the `vagrant-vbguest` plugin, new VBox GuestAdditions will be automatically rebuilt against the new version of your kernel (for which you would have downloaded the required headers in the second step above).

Once the GuestAdditions are back in shape, synchronized folders should be working again and the mapping of `/vagrant` should be successful.

Give it a try.

Comment: I wasn't able to follow the instruction precisely, but simply installing vagrant-vbguest plugin before building my VM seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer so instructions should be now more precise

Comment: I have similar issue.. After docker installation I can't connect homestead machine for my laravel project.. There is a point I couldn't understand in your solution, How are you able to run this command, "$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)",  on guest while you cannot connect to the vm?